# How freebase search suggests?

Tags: search, freebase

I know that search has a ranking system, but for example if i type washington to search box does it suggest every possible node that are connected to the nodes contains washington in its name or does it also suggests anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of documentation regarding [Freebase Search](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview), including [search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search).

To see how freebase.com uses this API just open the Chrome developer tools and check the API ajax requests, I got this typing washington:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?callback=jQuery17108071434691082686_1408371309116&query=washington&key=AIzaSyCQVC9yA72POMg2VjiQhSJQQP1nf3ToZTs&filter=(not+type%3A%2Fcommon%2Fdocument)&filter=(any+type%3A%2Fcommon%2Ftopic)&spell=always&exact=false&lang=s%2Fen%2Cd%2Fen%2Cs%2Fall%2Cd%2Fall&prefixed=true
```